# If $S = P^{-1}(0)$ is a surface, show $\int |K|\leq 4\pi C(d)$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

> Let $P\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$ be an irreducible polynomial, such that $S=P^{-1}(0)$ is a non compact regular surface. If $K$ denotes the Gaussian curvature, prove that:$$\int_S |K|\leq 4\pi C(d)$$ Where $C(d)$ is a constant dependent on the degree of P.

If it were compact, one could take the maximum value of $|K|$ and use it to conjure an upper bound. Furthermore, if it were compact, Chern-Lashoff's Theorem would use the fact that the normal map is onto in order to gain a lower bound $\int_S |K| \geq 4 \pi$. However these techniques are all dependent on compactness, which means I really do not know how to estimate this integral.

Comment: I like this question. Where did you find it?

Comment: It is from an old differential geometry exam at IMPA.

Comment: I suggest you first try to estimate the integral outside a large ball where the top order terms dominate the other terms.

Comment: Perhaps you should think of this as the pullback of an integral from $S^2$, averaging the number of critical points of projection on each (oriented) line. What is the greatest number of times $\nabla P$ can point in an arbitrary direction?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the script from that lecture/course as well. Since it is an exam question, the answer will probably be rather straightforward.

Comment: The course script may be found here:  https://impa.br/en_US/ensino/programas-de-formacao/mestrado-academico/disciplinas-mestrado-academico/geometria-diferencial-de-curvas-e-superficies/